# Local (dev) hosts domains ignored, but 'blocking' domains works...?

Tags: laravel, ip, hosts

I am running Virtual Machine with Laravel project.

Typing 192.168.10.10 in browser re-directs correctly onto Laravel home page.
Typing testing.test is googling 'testing.test'. Tried across IE/Edge, Opera, Chrome.

My Homestead.yaml config is:

```
sites:
    - map: testing.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

My hosts file is:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.10.10 testing.test
```

Interestingly - if I add

```
127.0.0.1       www.stackoverflow.com
```

Stackoverflow will get 'blocked'.

Also pinging testing.test from commander gives positive response from 192.168.10.10.

Tried flashing DNS, turning off IPv6. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding http:// in front of testing.test in hosts file helped. Also cleared dns from chrome and opera.
So the hosts file looks now:

```
192.168.10.10 http://testing.test www.testing.test testing.test
```